# Cast Android screen to PC monitor

Tags: miracast

I want to cast my android screen to pc monitor that doesn't have HDMI,only DVI and VGA.Is it possible to do this by using [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MJDYH21)
adapter and miracast device with HDMI?

Comment: The adapter should not be a problem as HDMI (the old versions) and DVI are identical on protocol level. But before buying a Miracast adapter I would make sure your phone really has this option. An easier way may be to use `scrcpy` over ADB/USB and a connected PC.

Comment: I already have a Miracast adapter and also my phone has the option to cast,what i don't have is the HDMI - DVI adapter.I already cast my Android to TV.

Comment: The adaptor should work fine

Comment: I hope it will.

Comment: It doesn't work